# How to make a flashing image in imgui?

Tags: c++, imgui

Now I have a image, have given a abstract method of creating texture (Dp2Px converts int to float)

```
Gluint mImageTexture = CreateTexture(Resource::getInst()->getImageOne());
ImGui::Image((void*)(intptr_t)mImageTexture, ImVec2(Dp2Px(55), Dp2Px(55)), ImVec2(0, 0), ImVec2(1, 1), ImVec4(1, 1, 1, 1));
```

Now I want to the image to flash like giving an alert, I tried using a counter but image flashing was not noticeable. I can't use sleep() as it would mean the whole program would sleep instead of only the image.
So how to go about this one?

Comment: Create a frame counter outside the drawing loop. When you want to start displaying the image, set frame counter to say 100. Call `ImGui::Image` only if the counter is greater than 0, and if so, also decrement the counter. Thus the image will be visible for 100 frames

Comment: If you want it to infinitely turning on and off every N frames, then you can increase the counter every frame, if `frame_counter / (2*N) < N` you draw the image, otherwise you don't. So the image will be shown for first N frames, then invisible for the next N frames, and so on repeatedly